# ASP.NET MVC Web API Routing: Multiple actions found matching the request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Suppose I have the following two controllers in the code below with two different routes:

```html
 [RoutePrefix("api/reportDelivery")]
    public class ReportDeliveryController : ApiController
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// called as: http://localhost:1607/api/ReportDelivery/invoice?id=3
        
        [Route("Invoice/{id?}")]
        public Models.Report GetDeliveredInvoice(int id)
        {
           
        }
        [Route("Invoices/{id?}")]
        public Models.Report GetDeliveredInvoices(int id)
        {
          

        }
```

I need to call each api as:

1. http://localhost:1607/api/ReportDelivery/invoice?id=3
2. http://localhost:1607/api/ReportDelivery/invoices?id=3

I used "s" to illustrate the difference in names. However, it gives me an error "multiple actions found matching the request".
This is the WebApiConfig:

```html
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Global.asax:

```html
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

           
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to enable the attribute mapping using  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

Comment: I have already tried this, which gives me another error: "The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code."

Comment: what is the other error? have you tried commenting out the MapHttpRoute code and with just the attribute routing?

Comment: 404 error when commenting the MapHttpRoute

Comment: this code works, there seems no problem here. You said "two controllers" what about the otrher ?

Comment: other controllers work fine because they use default Http verbs (get, post) with different params. but the same problem occurs when having get with the same number and type of params

Comment: Might be shooting in the dark but you could also try this URL http://localhost:1607/api/ReportDelivery/invoice/3

Comment: wow, waht is the downvoting for?

Comment: @Sam.C, the same error 404 Page not found

Answer (score 0):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller="ReportDelivery", action="GetDeliveryInvoice", id = RouteParameter.Optional } );
```

> complete path has to be defined.

controller
action
parameters

u did not define action segment.